# How to delete an Object whose associating use_count is bigger than 1?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14, smart-pointers

I have an Object with multiple `shared_ptrs` pointing to it, and its reference count `use_count` in the associating control block is bigger than 1.

Now, I want to deconstruct the Object, but I do not know where are all those `shared_ptrs`, so I cannot find and deconstruct them before I deconstruct the Object.

If I just deconstruct the Object, it will make those `shared_ptrs` become dangling. Therefore, under this situation, how to delete the Object with `use_count` bigger than 1 but have no idea about all its `shared_ptrs`?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You need to redesign your program so it doesn't share objects where it shouldn't.

Comment: Make some of them `weak_ptr`s so that the object can die before they do?

Comment: Fix the real problem, you basically have a resource managment issue. Trying to force delete is just blinding yourself to the fact that you have a design problem. know the lifecycle of your objects, understand ownership and reduce the use of shared_ptr's to a minimum.

Comment: @sorosh_sabz It's not a bad practice, it completely wrong. Those shared pointer will not "register" this deletion and will try to delete the managed object as well, which will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: @sorosh_sabz - If you are gonna post dangerous, wrong and misleading "solutions", please do it in the answer section where they may get the peer review they deserve. Do not abuse the comment section.

Comment: Your question is basically "how to do something I really should not do". Shared pointers are meant to be valid. Most likely, this is an XY problem, you might be better off describing what the structure you generated is meant to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to code of `Object` class and can modify it then you can do following steps (you may jump straight away to final code afterwards):

1. Create special structure `Fields` that contains all fields of original `Object`.
2. Store `Fields` as heap-allocated pointer field `p_`.
3. In original `Object` class make all original fields as references pointing to fields of `Fields` heap allocated object.
4. Add `destroyed_` bool flag that marks that `Object` was already destroyed. This flag becomes `true` after first call of destructor.
5. In every method check that `destroyed_` is not true, otherwise throw an exception. Because NONE of methods can be used when object is already destroyed. You may also just show a message with some error instead of throwing exception and return from method without doing anything. Up to you how to handle this error.
6. Inside destructor on first call make all cleanup as usual. And mark `destroyed_` as `true`. Second call to destructor should just silently exit due to destroyed_ being already true.
7. All copy constructors and assignment operators should be implemented as usual. Example in code below.

To delete object before all shared pointers are freed just call `ptr->~Object();` destructor, here `ptr` is any shared pointer, or use a convenience function [std::destroy_at](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy_at), like this `std::destroy_at(ptr.get());`.

In code below if last `DoSomething()` is not called (try to comment it out) then program finishes without exception, although warning is shown about calling destructor second time.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/MjqT1xzdE)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Object {
public:
    Object()
        : p_(new Fields{}), f0_(p_->f0_), f1_(p_->f1_) {}

    Object(Object const & o)
        : p_(new Fields{}), f0_(o.f0_), f1_(o.f1_) {}
    
    Object & operator = (Object const & o) {
        f0_ = o.f0_;
        f1_ = o.f1_;
        return *this;
    }

    void DoSomething() {
        if (destroyed_)
            throw std::runtime_error("Object already destroyed!");
        f0_ += 1;
        f1_ += std::to_string(f0_) + " ";
        std::cout << "DoSomething: '" << f1_ << "'" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Object() {
        if (destroyed_) {
            std::cout << "Called destructor of destroyed object..."
                << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        // Process fields cleanup here...
        delete p_;
        p_ = nullptr;
        destroyed_ = true;
    }

private:
    struct Fields {
        int f0_ = 0;
        std::string f1_;
    };

    Fields * p_ = nullptr;
    bool destroyed_ = false;

    int & f0_;
    std::string & f1_;
};

int main() {
    try {
        std::shared_ptr<Object> o0 = std::make_shared<Object>();
        {
            std::shared_ptr<Object> o1 = o0;
            o1->DoSomething();
            o1->DoSomething();
            // Call destructor when you don't need object.
            // Even if some shared_ptrs still use it.
            o1->~Object();
        }
        o0->DoSomething();
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception const & ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
DoSomething: '1 '
DoSomething: '1 2 '
Called destructor of destroyed object...
Exception: Object already destroyed!
```

---

Similar code to above can be also implemented using C++17 [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) instead of heap pointer, this solution is even better because it doesn't use any heap allocation, all fields are located inside object's body (i.e. stack allocation).

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/869bhb5zd)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <optional>

class Object {
public:
    Object()
        : p_(Fields{}), f0_(p_->f0_), f1_(p_->f1_) {}

    Object(Object const & o)
        : p_(Fields{}), f0_(o.f0_), f1_(o.f1_) {}
    
    Object & operator = (Object const & o) {
        f0_ = o.f0_;
        f1_ = o.f1_;
        return *this;
    }

    void DoSomething() {
        if (destroyed_)
            throw std::runtime_error("Object already destroyed!");
        f0_ += 1;
        f1_ += std::to_string(f0_) + " ";
        std::cout << "DoSomething: '" << f1_ << "'" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Object() {
        if (destroyed_) {
            std::cout << "Called destructor of destroyed object..."
                << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        // Process fields cleanup here...
        p_ = std::nullopt;
        destroyed_ = true;
    }

private:
    struct Fields {
        int f0_ = 0;
        std::string f1_;
    };

    std::optional<Fields> p_;
    bool destroyed_ = false;

    int & f0_;
    std::string & f1_;
};

int main() {
    try {
        std::shared_ptr<Object> o0 = std::make_shared<Object>();
        {
            std::shared_ptr<Object> o1 = o0;
            o1->DoSomething();
            o1->DoSomething();
            // Call destructor when you don't need object.
            // Even if some shared_ptrs still use it.
            o1->~Object();
        }
        o0->DoSomething();
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception const & ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
DoSomething: '1 '
DoSomething: '1 2 '
Called destructor of destroyed object...
Exception: Object already destroyed!
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to delete an Object whose associating use_count is bigger than 1?

By reducing the use count to 0. This can be achieved by destroying or reassigning the shared pointers that currently point to the object.

> but I do not know where are all those shared_ptrs

Then you must solve the problem that prevents you from knowing all those pointers.

Or, you could consider that perhaps there is a reason why those pointers exist, and that perhaps the object isn't supposed to be deleted yet, since it's apparently being used by some part of the program.